# Answers By Crashlytics - adding custom event

Tags: swift, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I have an app using Crashlytics with Answers. Both are working right, and I am seeing events that are built into the framework being tracked.

I am trying to add a custom event, by using the following line of code in my View Controller:

```
Answers.logCustomEventWithName("Flight Complete", customAttributes: nil)
```

My issue is that the compiler doesn't recognize the Answers object. It just tells me "Use of unresolved identifier "Answers"" Which makes sense because I've never declared it.

I am unsure of where or how to create this Answers object, as it is already integrated and working for default events. Does anyone know where I should declare it for use across the app? (AppDelegate?) or what the declaration looks like? They don't show it in the docs.

Thanks

UPDATE: Here's what I've tried adding to AppDelegate but still not recognizing "Answers" object...

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self, Answers.self])
```

Comment: 1. Have you enable `Answer` on Fabric dashboard? 2. You should refresh your Fabric & Crashlytics library 3. Last, Clean projects and retry

Comment: I did enable answer, and built the project with it saying Answers was installed and everything. Will try a project clean and rebuild... is there any other declaration im missing?

Comment: Clean did not fix the issue, when trying to build it still tells me it is an unresolved identifier.

Comment: Did you import the lib? `import Crashlytics`

Comment: I only have `Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])` in my app, can you check if you have `import Crashlytics` where you call `Answers.log`?

Comment: I don't know what I was thinking... I needed to import crashlytics on the view itself of course. Stupid... I really appreciate the help. How did I not think of this...

Comment: @Breek I will make my Fabric.with() match yours.. I was hacking in desperation when I added Answer.self there. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Wanted to close this question since it is now answered from the comments:

I failed to call

```
import Crashlytics
```

At the top of the view controller like a complete idiot.

Also, I had added

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self, Answers.self])
```

When it is correct as:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])
```

Answers is included in the Crashlytics call.