# Delete custom event in Answers Fabric

Tags: google-fabric

Im trying to delete an already reported custom event in answers, because I'm using string and not number. Which the initial event was reported with. Is there any way to delete an event?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here. Currently, deleting events from Fabric isn't possible. An event will be removed automatically if no data is received for the event within a thirty day window. If you switch from a String or Number, to the other, then the event will automatically switch to showing those values once we detect more events of the new type.

Comment: In order to prevent "pollution" of real data with test data, is it feasible to use `Dashboard -> Settings -> Apps -> [app] -> Delete App` once the initial test of analytics is complete ? So that only real data is once again stored and visible to the business.

Comment: Im doing this myself, deleting versions that was used for test. And also having test apps.

Comment: You could also change the bundle id or package name of your app and use them for different sets of data when testing.

Comment: how can i add custom event in my app extension like share extension, document provider extension?

Comment: @MikeBonnell any chance of deleting events being added as a feature?

Comment: It's not on our immediate roadmap to add in @masterwok.

Comment: I can see how deleting events may cause trouble when older app keep reporting those events. But how about adding a "[x] Hide this Event" on the specific event view.  Consider it an internal event attribute if you like.  And then filter it away unless "Show Hidden Events" is clicked.  Add this next to "Show All Events" in the events overview.  At least do something, there's a clear need here.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Stephen and definitely understand the desire from app teams for the functionality.

Comment: but how about adding new event ? because right now im taking over exisiting project and wanted to add more events. i did add in the code but its not reflecting to the fabric page itself. any idea how ? Thanks man!

Comment: @MinaMakhtar You are asking a different question so I'd recommend either posting a new question with your specifics or looking at a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35384316/answers-by-crashlytics-adding-custom-event